# Move device to another iothub via Custom Allocation Function

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have a DPS Allocation Policy implemented via a custom Function App to theoretically allow for moving devices between iothubs at will.  A fresh provisioning appears to work as expected, but I can't figure out how I can move the device to another hub.  It appears once the device is provisioned, it never hits DPS again.

I first tried rebooting the device and then tried the following iotedge (V1.4) commands to hopefully reprovision the device.

```
$ sudo iotedge config apply
$ sudo iotedge system reprovision
```

My attempts usually end with the following when iotedge runs up:

```
Error in watchdog: Failed to update $edgeAgent identity: Hub client error
```

Can you 'hot' move a device between iothubs using DPS?  Is there perhaps some state that needs to be wiped/reset of the device to force that provision function to fire again?

Answer (score 0):

In the `/etc/aziot/config.toml` file, you should find the following line:

```
# auto_reprovisioning_mode = Dynamic
```

You can uncomment that, and change it to `AlwaysOnStartup`

```
auto_reprovisioning_mode = AlwaysOnStartup
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-devices-at-scale-linux-symmetric?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=individual-enrollment%2Cubuntu#provision-the-device-with-its-cloud-identity):

Dynamic - Reprovision when the device detects that it may have been moved from one IoT Hub to another. *This is the default.*

AlwaysOnStartup - Reprovision when the device is rebooted or a crash causes the daemon(s) to restart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If 'dynamic' is the default, how does it detect that the device has been moved, if it's not hitting the custom DPS allocation function?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. I suspect it happens when it can't reach the Hub. But there's a specific configuration for that. Check out the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/1025af2e462968a07035b27bb99c872795409462/edgelet/contrib/config/linux/template.toml#L67), maybe there's some hints in the code.